# Processing a LiDAR image to be more detailed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, lidar, arcgis-10.8

I'm using ArcMap 10.8 to try and find old roadbeds. The DEM data I downloaded is very dark and shaded. You can't see anything at lower elevations. I have the hillshade effect turned on but you can't see any ground details.

[image]

I don't want the dark shading and I need to be able to see every detail on the ground. I don't know how to process the data to make it more light and detailed (2nd image).

[image]

I've tried the resample tool but it didn't do anything. And I haven't been able to change the values to see if that would help. The values for the 1st image is a low of 807.5ft and a high of 3001.63ft. The 2nd is a low of 0 and a high of 254 and I don't know the unit of measurement. They're both in the same general area but the 2nd image doesn't have everything I need.

How do I process the DEM data to be more detailed?

Comment: Change the colour ramp of the DEM to what every you like, there are presets, then set transparency to say 50% to allow the hill shade to show through?

Comment: What is the resolution and source of your dem?  If it is older LiDAR the resolution may be lower, if it is 1m LiDAR then you have a good chance.  Don't reproject it before creating the hillshade.  I recall making a hillshade in ArcGIS required an extension but you could download and use QGIS (free) and have several tools to make a hillshade.  I prefer the GDAL tool with the multidirectional lighting, but you can make a few hillshades using different options and some may show a road better than others.

Comment: You can't reprocess data to make it more light (less dark).  That's just a matter of symbology.  Change the colour range/combination of the symbology to what you need.  You also can't reprocess a DEM to magically incorporate more detail without going back to the original data (eg, LiDAR) that it was generated from.  For getting more details, check the original LiDAR to find out how many points per square metre it is, and also check what the resolution of the DEM is.  If the LiDAR ppsm is sufficient, then you may be able to regenerate a new DEM from the LiDAR at a higher resolution.

Comment: What is the resolution (cell size) of your DEM?